# python flask app mod_wsgi/apache

Tags: python, flask, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm working on getting my python flask app on my linode server. I've followed a few tutorials to get this configured, but am stuck because when I visit the url, i get this error. "ImportError: No module named ugpromo". I've seen other problems like this on stackoverflow, and have tried their solutions, but I still get the same error.

wsgi file

```
import sys                                                                                                              
import logging                                                                                                          
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)                                                                                  
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/html/codingbybrandon/public_html/ugpromo/")                                                                                                                                                                         
from ugpromo import app as application                                                                                  
application.secret_key = 'Add your secret key'
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask                                                                                                 
app = Flask(__name__)                                                                                                   
@app.route("/")                                                                                                         
def hello():                                                                                                                
  return "Hello, I love Digital Ocean!"                                                                               
if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                                      
  app.run()
```

virtual host file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                                                              
ServerName ugpromo.codingbybrandon.com                                                                                  
ServerAdmin admin@codingbybrandon.com                                                                                   
ServerAlias www.ugpromo.codingbybrandon.com                                                                             
WSGIScriptAlias / 
/var/www/html/codingbybrandon.com/public_html/ugpromo/ugpromo.wsgi                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
   <Directory /var/www/html/codingbybrandon/public_html/ugpromo/ugpromo/>                                                         
 Order allow,deny                                                                                                         
 Allow from all                                                                                                  
   </Directory>                                                                                                                                                          
   Alias /static 
  /var/www/codingbybrandon.com/public_html/ugpromo/ugpromo/static                                            
   <Directory 
    /var/www/codingbybrandon.com/public_html/ugpromo/ugpromo/static/>                                                    
     Order allow,deny                                                                                                        
     Allow from all                                                                                                  
 </Directory>                                                                                                            
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log                                                                                    
   LogLevel warn                                                                                                           
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined                                                                 
 </VirtualHost>
```

directory listing is as follows

```
public_html
  ugpromo
    __init__.py
    ugpromo
      static
      templates
      ugp
   ugpromo.wsgi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've added the outer "ugpromo" directory - the one containing the `__init__` file you want to import - to your sys.path. You need to add the *parent* of that directory instead:

```
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/html/codingbybrandon/public_html/")
```

(Note, however, you really shouldn't be putting code under public_html. Place it somewhere else.)

Comment: still getting the same error after I updated that path. Thanks for that advice.  I'm just a programmer, so by using a server I have to configure, I hope to learn more about the configuration files and settings.

Comment: after doing more research I changed who apache was running as, but that didn't fix it, just wanted to update with something else I tried.

Comment: I solved this issue, and the problem was very very stupid. I the folder name codingbybrandon is really codingbybrandon.com. I will mark this answer as correct though, as I am using the parent directory as well which I wasn't before.